# Passing ruby tag in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to change my application back ground dynamically.For that background image, i'm saving the image in DB with only one row,if i upload new background image it will update the DB first row and it will affect background as well.

here is my view code

```
<%=ChangeBackdrops.first.media.url%>
```

here is my css

```
body {
  background-image: url(/../../../images/back.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
  background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
```

How can I pass my ruby tag in that CSS? That means like this?

```
background-image: url(<%=ChangeBackdrops.first.media.url%>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way you can achieve that is just placing the code inside the `style` tag while rendering the view. Try writing the following code inside the `application.html.erb` (for example):

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" ... /> <!-- load your common stylesheet --!>
  <!-- and now override the background-image --!>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url("#{ChangeBackdrops.first.media.url}");
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: <link href="/stylesheets/floating_backdrop_settings.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
i loaded like this. Is this correct? For this not working.

Comment: What returned value of `ChangeBackdrops.first.media.url` looks like?

Comment: Thats working,but i dont want the style tag inside the application.html.erb.

Comment: @Ruk I am in the same situation.  Though I didn't think I wanted a stylesheet tag in the `html.erb` file, I think now it's needed: since it is runtime, there is no caching typical to precompiled assets; and sending another CSS file would just slow down the page render time by adding more files to load.  just put all your in-page styles in a sane place.

Answer (score 0):

What rails version do you use? Do you use Asset Pipeline? In that case you can just add erb extension to your css file and use your suggested line `<%=ChangeBackdrops.first.media.url%>`. You may want to check [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html),  the 'preprocessing' part of it

Comment: More elaborate answer along the same lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338173/possible-to-use-stylesheet-css-erb-in-rails/10075329#10075329

Comment: My image name is dynamic.not a constant (single)name.