# How do I require main.css.erb in application.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My `application.css` is

```
 *= require_self
 *= require 'main.css'
 *= require 'styles.css'
 *= require 'jquery.ui'
 *= require 'main.css.erb'
 */
```

but `main.css.erb` is not included which contains

```
 background-image: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'data.png' %>) !important;
```

My main page is

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', :media => "all",'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

I dont want to use `*= require_tree.` in `application.css` so that page specific css will remain separate to each other.

How can I use `main.css.erb` in `RAILS 4` development and assets pipeline in `production` Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I dont want to use *= require_tree. in application.css so that page
>   specific css will remain separate to each other.**

In that case, why don't you include the file in your `layout` directly:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  'application', 'main', :media => "all",'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This will allow you to include the CSS file separately, both in development & production.

Of course, this recommendation is discounting the naming & file extension issues that you have:

---

[**Precompile**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production)

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.

You mention you want to keep your file separate from other CSS. `require_tree` is exactly the same as `require` -- it calls a file to be *included* in your `application.css` file.

There is nothing wrong with this, except if you want to include the files separately, you'll want to ensure you *keep* them separate. To do this, you should assign the `main` to your precompilation array:

```
#config/application.rb
config.assets.precompile += ["main.css"]
```

This means that when you run your application in production, you'll be able to use the `main.css` file independent of any other.

--

**Name**

Finally, and probably most poignantly, you'll need to make sure you call only one file `main`. The reason is that regardless of whether you use `css`, `erb` or `scss`, the file will always be transformed into a `css` file

This means if you have multiple files with the same name, Rails will become confused (as you've discovered). To remedy this, you have to ensure you're able to name the files you need individually

--

[**Preprocessor**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing)

Finally, as mentioned by `Sampriti Panda`, you should opt to use `scss` preprocessor over `erb` in your asset pipeline. The main reason for this is that the preprocessor allows you to precompile the assets with impunity

I'd change your `erb` file to this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss
.your_element {
    background-image: asset_url('data.png');
}
```

This will work both as a dynamic and static file

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have 2 main.css included.

Try changing your code into this :

```
*= require_self
 *= require main
 *= require styles
 *= require jquery.ui
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `main.css` and a `main.css.erb` file? If so, then those two files are the same for sprockets, and hence only the first one (`main.css`) is included.

Rename one of the files and get rid of the file extensions in your manifest file, i.e.:

```
*= require_self
*= require main
*= require styles
*= require jquery.ui
*= require main2
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075329/1466095

> From rails 3.1 asset pipeline enables you to use asset helpers inside
>   your css file. The css parsers is not binded a controller/action
>   scope, but the ruby parser is now able to resolve some issues like
>   image path references

So you can rename it as `main.css.scss` inside the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory and it should work.