# Rails stylesheet not changing in local host

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, assets

The original stylesheet for my index.html.erb page was home.scss, but I tried to change it to home.scss.erb. I made the file, moved it into assets/stylesheets, and changed the `</link>` tag, but when I go to http://localhost:3000/home/index, it says that I'm still using home.scss. Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use embedded ruby in your css. [Refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338173/possible-to-use-stylesheet-css-erb-in-rails) where they describe how you can embedd ruby in your css through the asset pipline.

What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to make a background image for a top section. I'm very new to Rails, sorry if it's pretty obvious

Comment: After some more research it looks like there are some other ways to embed ruby in your stylesheets. But that's not what you need.

[Check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257555/how-to-reference-images-in-css-within-rails-4) for how to use rails image tags in your css